# cambiar valor de propiedades de modelo recibido en controller MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una aplicacion ASP.NET MVC en la que a través de un controller recibo un modelo desde una vista (lo normal de MVC) tal como muestro.

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult EnviarEALG(Modelo datos)
            { }
```

Pero ahora por necesidad debo presentar ese modelo que recibo en el controller en una vista pero con un cambio en una de sus propiedades string llamado acción la cual llega con el valor de "nuevo" pero cuando reenvie el modelo quiero enviarlo con el valor de "segundo registro".
Igualmente quiero que tres propiedades específicas no se reenvien con el valor recibido sino que el valor sean cadenas vacías, de momento lo hago asi

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EnviarEALG(Modelo datos)
        {
                datos.accion = "nuevo valor";
                datos.nombres = "";
                datos.cargo = "";
                datos.nivel = "";
            return View(datos);
        }
```

lo que he decidido es utilizar ViewBag para enviar el valor a la vista y luego mediante javascript asignar el nuevo valor a la propiedad deseada de esta forma (idAccion es el id del Html.EditorFor)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var accion = '@ViewBag.accion';
    alert(accion);
    $("#idAccion").val('');
    $("#idAccion").val(accion);   
</script>
```

En el Alert de JavaScript me aparece el valor deseado pero aun con  `$("#idAccion").val(accion);` en la vista fuertemente tipada (Modelo) siempre me aparecen los valores originales, como puedo hacer para cambiar los valores en el controller y recibir los valores que quiero en mi vista? gracias.

Estas son las propiedades que deseo cambiar y que están en la clase Modelo.

```
 public string accion { get; set; }
 public string nombres { get; set; }
 public string cargo { get; set; }
 public string nivel { get; set; }
```

y en la vista, esta es una de las propiedad a la que deseo cambiarle el valor

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.accion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.accion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "idAccion", @value = "@ViewBag.accion" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.accion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

pero me sigue apareciendo el valor original, no lo cambia.

Comment: Por favor, incluye dentro de la pregunta el código de tu vista. Para poder colaborarte un poco mejor.

Comment: Listo, he decidido utilizar ViewBag y JS pero aun no logro cambiar el valor

Comment: Con el Helper `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.accion)`, te debería funcionar sin problema. Me entra la duda que ahora hablas de `js`. Podria ser que tu `js` este alterando los valores?. Intenta revisar el script del cual haces mención. También te sugiero que a manera de prueba adiciones otro `input` a la vista con `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.accion)` haber si te da el mismo problema.

Comment: listo, he utilizado en el helper lo siguiente: Html.EditorFor(model => model.accion, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.accion, id = "idAccion" } }) y me ha funcionado, lo importante es cambiar el valor en Value = ViewBag.accion...antes de Html, class, id lleva arroba

Comment: Ok, me alegra que se te haya resuelto el problema. Te recomiendo que si tienes el nivel para publicar respuestas. Añadas la solución que encontraste a tu pregunta, para que otras personas puedan accederla mas fácilmente.

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez bien dicho, PabloMayora, recuerda que puedes marcar tu respuesta como válida dando clic en el ☑ en un periodo de 48 horas a partir de la publicación de tu respuesta :D

Comment: Gracias Weimar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de cambiar el valor de las propiedades del modelo desde el controller, envio un valor a traves de ViewBag y luego se lo asigno a la propiedad del modelo que me interesa, asi en el controller creo

```
 ViewBag.accion = "solicitud creada con un empleado registrado";
```

y en la vista la asigno de esta manera

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.accion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.accion, @id = "idAccion" } })
```